# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given and empty tkinter

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, printing

Saw some similar posts about this, but they used something called Django?

First of all, this is school assignment, i know stack overflow isnt to fond of us students asking for stuff. I just wanted to clarify that.

First code runs, but when I close it, the error occurs. And in my tkinter window nothing appears.

The issue lies in the following line of code:

```py
board2 = EQ([0, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 3])
```

The main function is there to test class for a correct solution. This is a Eight Queens problem.
Hope someone can help me out.

Here is the rest of my code for context:
If the code doesnt make sense, here is an image of the assignment, https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE9F0.jpg.

```py
from tkinter import *

SIZE = 8

class EQ:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queens = SIZE * [-1]

        window = Tk()
        window.title("Eight Queens")

        window.mainloop()
    
    def get(self, i):
        return self.queens[i]
    
    def set(self, i, j):
        self.queens[i] = j

    def is_solved(self):
        for i in range(0, 8):
            #If two queens are in same row
            for j in range(i + 1, 8):
                if self.queens[i] == self.queens[j]:
                    return False

            #Diagonal down       
            count = 1
            for j in range(i + 1, 8):
                if count + self.queens[i] == self.queens[j]:
                    return
                count += 1
            
            #Diagonal up
            count = 1
            for j in range(i + 1, 8):
                if self.queens[i] - count == self.queens[j]:
                    return False
                count += 1
        
        return True
    
    def print_board(self):
        for i in range(0, 8):
            for j in range(0,8):
                print("|", end = " ")
                if self.queens[j] == i:
                    print("X", end = " ")
                else:
                    print(" ", end = " ")
            print("|")

def main():

    board1 = EQ()
    board1.set(0, 2)
    board1.set(1, 4)
    board1.set(2, 7)
    board1.set(3, 1)
    board1.set(4, 0)
    board1.set(5, 3)
    board1.set(6, 6)
    board1.set(7, 5)

    print("Is board1 a correct eight queen placement?",
        board1.is_solved())

    board2 = EQ([0, 4, 7, 5, 2, 6, 1, 3])

    if board2.is_solved():
        print("Eight queens are placed correctly in board2")
        board2.print_board()

    else:
        print("Eight queens are placed incorrectly in board2")

main()
```

Comment: `EQ([...])` would cause an error because `EQ` doesn't take any arguments (as defined by the `__init__` magic method but you are passing one.

Comment: You don't need tkinter at all.  To fix the issue, make constructor of `EQ` accepts an optional list.

Comment: you're right with tkinter, but how do i make it accept an optional list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need tkinter at all as the application has just console output.

As the current constructor of `EQ` does not accept argument, so the second instance creation will raise the error.

To fix it, just modify constructor of `EQ` to accept optional list:

```py
class EQ:
    def __init__(self, queens=None):
        self.queens = queens if queens else SIZE*[-1]
        # removed tkinter stuff
    ...
```

Comment: works perfectly! thanks!